# Trying to convert xml into csv

Tags: python, xml, csv

I'm trying to convert xml into csv using python and I have attached my code below.
I don't know where I'm going wrong.. it's not happening.. 
I tried different ways and after several changes and modifications, I'm stuck with this.

I thought this was legit, but still its not working.
Could anyone help me out and tell me where I'm going wrong?

When I try to run it.. it prints (xxxxxxxxxxxx)
can anyone help me out?

```
                needed_data = open('C:\\Users\\dv\\NeededData.csv', 'w')
                csvwriter = csv.writerow(need_data)
                count = 0
                head = ['username']
                csvwriter.writerow(head)

                for process_inf in root.findall('processing_info'):
                    row = []
                    u_name = process_inf.find('username').text
                    row.append(username)

                    csvwriter.writerow(needed_head)
                needed_data.close()
```

sample xml file :

```
<processing_info username="437896" time="1536506399" done_by="BIBO"/>
```

desired csv:

```
username
437896
.
.
.
.
etc etc
```

Comment: You should check len with eqality operator (== or! =). You should also show, że how You run Your code. Consider using argparse module.

Comment: Share a sample of the input and a sample of the required output

Comment: I have added it

Comment: So your sample XML is one element of three attributes and you expect multiple CSV rows?

Comment: no it has many elements with many attributes.. I just need the username..
and yes.. multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly checking to see if the caller has passed an argument on the command line:

```py
if len(sys.argv) is not 2:
    print("xxxxxxxxxxx.")
```

If your code is printing `xxxxxxxxxxx.` then you are not providing the expected argument.  For example, if I place your code, unmodified, into a file called `readerusers.py`, if I run it like this:

```
python readusers.py
```

I get this output:

```
xxxxxxxxxxx.
```

But if I provide an argument:

```
python readuers.py something
```

Then it produces no output.

---

There are various other problems with your code; one that jumps out is this:

```
needed_data = open('C:\\Users\\dv\\NeededData.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writerow(need_data)
```

I think you mean:

```
csvwriter = csv.writer(need_data)
```

Comment: hi, I have forgot to set the parameter..
now after doing it and running it im getting this error
 u_name = process_inf.find('username').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'